# make svn st show status of new added share library

Tags: svn

By default, `svn st` will not show the status of a shared library that has not been checked in to the repository. How to make it visible?

```
>svn info lib/libjmfntv.so 
svn: 'lib/libjmfntv.so' is not under version control
>svn st 
Nothing will show up; however, I want it show up like below so that I can remember to add it into the repository 
?      lib/libjmfntv.so
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use no-ignore option

`svn status --no-ignore`